# Numpy fancy indexing resulting in selection with different shape

Tags: numpy

From the following snippet:

```
>>> palette = np.array( [ [0,0,0],                # black
...                       [255,0,0],              # red
...                       [0,255,0],              # green
...                       [0,0,255],              # blue
...                       [255,255,255] ] )       # white
>>> image = np.array( [ [ 0, 1, 2, 0 ],           # each value corresponds to a color in the palette
...                     [ 0, 3, 4, 0 ]  ] )
>>> brush = palette[image]                            # the (2,4,3) color image
array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [255,   0,   0],
        [  0, 255,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]],
       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0]]])
```

The variable `brush` has a shape of (2,4,3). Can anyone explain how/why applying a (2,4) shaped filter to a (5,3) shaped array results in an array of shape (2,4,3).?

Comment: It picks one row of `palette` for each element of `image`. `image` is (2,4), the result has a new trailing dimension of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your mask (in this case the array `image`) is an array with a shape `(2,4)`. Each element picked by the mask is 1d array with `3` elements. So, `brush` will have the shape `(2,4,3)`.

This might help you see the shape of the array `brush`:
[image]

To quote from [Numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays):

> In general, the shape of the resultant array will be the concatenation
>   of the shape of the index array (or the shape that all the index
>   arrays were broadcast to) with the shape of any unused dimensions
>   (those not indexed) in the array being indexed.

Answer (score 1):

The `palette[image[0]]` returns a 2d array of shape (4,3) obtained by stacking the rows 0, 1, 2 and 0 of `palette`. Analogously the `palette[image[1]]` stacks the rows 0, 3, 4, 0 of `palette`. The `palette[image]` stacks the two 2d arrays `palette[image[0]]` and `palette[image[1]]` to form a 3d array of shape (2, 4, 3).